# Formatting date within an array within a struct

Tags: date, go, struct, formatting, format

I am wanting to make sure that the DOB(Date of Birth) is formatted professionally and clearly instead of being a bland integer. I have tried using a constant to declare the layout like this

```
const (
    layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
    layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
)
date := "1999-12-31"
t, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, date)
fmt.Println(t)                  // 1999-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
fmt.Println(t.Format(layoutUS)) // December 31, 1999
```

but I can't seem to fit this into my context

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

)


func main() {
    const (
        layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
        layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
    )
    type aUser struct {
        userID       int
        username     string
        email        string
        DOB          int64
        registeredAt int64
    }

    type note struct {
        name   string
        status string
        users  []aUser
    }


    sally := aUser{01, "Sally", "sally@gmail.com", 112498, 1935}
    john := aUser{02, "John", "johnme@gmail.com", 112388, 1978}

    users := []aUser{sally, john}
    notes := note{"Grocery List", "Completed", users}

    fmt.Printf("notes are %v\n", notes)

}
```

Comment: That seems like an odd design choice to represent DOBs using a single integer composed out of 3 other MDY integers. If you can fix that, you should.

Comment: use t.Unix() to get the timestamp as a int64 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract year/month/date from the numeric type with division and modulo operations, then write them to a string using C-style string formatting with `fmt.Sprintf()`.

```golang
var dob uint64 = 112498
date := fmt.Sprintf("19%02d-%02d-%02d", dob % 100, dob / 10000, (dob / 100) % 100)
fmt.Println(date) // 1998-11-24
```

Be warned your date format is missing century and millennium information, so in the above code I guessed that the year is 19XX (as opposed to 20XX, etc.).